# Should the Supplier, Client and User tables be combined

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I currently have 3 table and I am unsure if they should be merged or not. They do have similar fields, and a supplier would need to login at some point or another, and even clients

User

- Username
- Password
- Name
- Surname
- Mobile
- Telephone
- Email

Client

- Name
- Telephone
- Email
- Fax
- VatNo

Supplier

- Name
- Telephone
- Email
- Fax
- VATNo
- LastRefreshDate
- OpeningHoursId

Can somebody give me a suggestion as he best way to go forward.

Comment: I'd leave them separate. You might want to consider using common tables for contact information and allowing for multiple contacts at clients and suppliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables should probably not be merged. However, that's a judgement call based on guesses about what the tables mean.

It looks like clients and suppliers can be corporate entities (VAT numbers, for example), but users should be individuals rather than collective accounts.  You may well have a list of users associated with a given supplier; similarly, you may well have a list of users associated with a given client.  In some circumstances, a supplier may also be a client. You would need a User ID number in the Users table; you would need a Client ID number in the Clients table and a Supplier ID number in the Suppliers table. You would have simple mapping tables to list the Users associated with a Client and another to list the Users associated with the Suppliers.

However, a lot depends on whether the guesses I've made (plausible ones, but nonetheless guesses) are remotely on target.

Comment: so to see if i am getting what you are saying, the common attributes could be placed in a table and in which they would then be linked accordingly with the supplier/client/user

Comment: Maybe, but maybe not, too. It depends in part on what the significant differences are between suppliers and clients. A lot depends on the interpretation of the users. You bothered to call out clients and suppliers as different entity types; that was probably correct. You also called out users as different from either suppliers or clients; that was probably correct too.  What you've not discussed at all is what clients are (can do, need recorded), nor what suppliers are, nor what users are. So, we can _guess_ — but there's that word again; guessing is not a good basis for analysis.